# macOS Big Sur creates duplicate versions of files

Tags: macos, command-line

Several times in a day, I notice duplicate versions of my files being created. Refer to the screenshot - `empty.html.erb` was duplicated, and a new `empty.html 2.erb` was created.

What is causing this, and how can I stop this?

[image]

I feel like this might have something to do with TimeMachine and backups, since it only started after I enabled backups to iCloud and moved my files from `~` to `~/Documents/`

Comment: Yes, I am sure that macOS is doing this - this also happens with files that are not part of my coding projects. I feel like this might have something to do with TimeMachine and backups, since it only started after I enabled backups to iCloud and moved my files from `~` to `~/Documents/`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're using git ontop of iCloud Drive. I.e. the problem is not with Time Machine and backups at all - it is instead that you have chosen to store your `~/Documents/` folder in iCloud Drive, which is not compatible with programs such as `git`.

The issue is that iCloud Drive treats each file as an individual and independent file, whereas git assumes a specific relationship between the files. Git uses hidden files that contain information about other files in the folder - it expects them to be "in sync" - and it expects it is the only program manipulating the files; this assumption does not necessarily hold here.

Imagine for example that you run a git operation that touches several files in your folder - it might move stuff around, delete and recreate, change access times, etc. It does so very quickly while keeping its own state. iCloud Drive is triggered by these changes and starts a sync - however there's a lag between git something and the sync being triggered. Then later iCloud Drive might have sent something to the server and received data back, and it goes to store it and sees that the file (or its metadata) has changed underneath it. Now iCloud Drive has a conflict that could be solved by overwriting your local file, trashing the file just received from the server - or as the case is here - preserving the new data by saving it with a "2", "3", "4", etc. suffix.

This problem is common with almost any file syncing system, so you would experience similar problems with Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

The solution to this is to not an iCloud Drive backed `Documents` folder, or move your git repository out of the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Developers should be able to get an [Oiroboros badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros) for unlocking this achievement. It will serve them well when they later instantiate it in their code... (as we all do at some point)

Comment: Strangely I've never run into this problem with Dropbox. I don't use it for a lot of source code, but the only downside I have encountered with it so far is an overabundance of activity in the logs from how many files get touched.

Comment: Moved my code out of `~/Documents` and can verify that this indeed is the problem. I wanted to create a secondary archive of all my projects ( other than GH ) in case of a disaster, and it looks like it isn't going to be easy...

Comment: For "disaster copies" you want backup - not a product like iCloud Drive, Dropbox, Google Drive or similar. Just use any backup system, and you should be ready to go!

Comment: (1) I've had the problem (iCloud duplicating files) as described here when git (or anything similar) is not involved.  And (2) I've used git within iCloud and dropbox folders without issue, as long as I only make changes on one machine at a time (so changes made by git are propagated to the other machines before I use git on them).  So in my experience this is a problem with iCloud that can be unrelated to Git. (3) When you say "received data back" from iCloud, what do you mean, and why would any such occurrence be specific to git as opposed to any other action that changes the file meanwhile?

Comment: @NealYoung I didn’t say that any of this is specific to git - so that answers your questions 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks.  Re (3) I'm genuinely curious -- do you know what data the local machine "receives back" from iCloud (that causes the local machine to make a duplicate of a changed file), assuming the file is not modified elsewhere meanwhile?  (If I understood better, maybe I could work around the issue.)

Comment: I can’t see why you would want to assume that it hasn’t been modified elsewhere - as that would be main (if not only) reason for a new file version to be received back.